# Android Studio: Gradle Build fails with error: Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.ndk.NdkPlugin'

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have just upgraded my build tools and my gradle plugin version to 0.14.0.

Gradle version - 2.1
Android Studio - 0.9.3

When m trying to do a build of my project I se the following error -

> Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.ndk.NdkPlugin'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process may be corrupt. Stop Gradle
>     daemons and sync project
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle
>   processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java
>   processes.

I've tried both the above options and also upgraded all my sdk components and I still see this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you also tried to clean your project ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try cleaning your project and re-build.